# Windows PowerShell script for verifying several Active Directory groups exist

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to run a PowerShell script to verify that a huge list of Active Directory groups exist based on an `.xlsx` file. I would also like to see the owners of the AD groups if possible.

I can run separate scripts, if needed. Please help.

Comment: this site is for help with your code [*grin*] ... so, what have you tried? what failed to work as needed? what errors did you get? ///// please, read the Tour page for this site ... it will help you make a good Question.

Comment: I noticed there were other questions regarding windows power shell which is why I posted my question here. Here is what I tried    "@("group-1", "group-2", "group-n") | % {Get-ADGroup $_}" - This worked but I need to import a large list and I tried running this script without success "Import-Csv "./path-to-file | % { Get-AdGroup $_.name }"

Comment: If its a CSV file than you would want something like $list = (Import-Csv -path 'filename').GroupNames

Comment: @Mitchell - please, always put your code in the Question with formatting markers around it. right now, the code in your comment is nearly unreadable. ///// also, "without success" is rather vague. [*grin*] you would likely do better to describe what result you got & how it failed to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing to an excel file from PowerShell is its own adventure, but one that is heavily documented if you google it.

For the query you are asking, its important to know if you have the group's Display Name or the group's SamAccountName.  If you have both, you could put an -OR in the filter.

Here is a quick example of how it could work based on a text list.

```
$list = 'Cross Functional Team
Security Group
Bobs Team' -split([Environment]::NewLine)

$SelectSplat = @{
    Property = @{n='Name';E={$_}},
               @{N='Found';e={[Bool](Get-adgroup -Filter {DisplayName -eq $_})}},
               @{N='ManagedBy';e={Get-adgroup -Filter {DisplayName -eq $_} -Properties ManagedBy | %{(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.ManagedBy).Name}}}
}

$list | Select-Object @SelectSplat
```

Comment: Thank you, Once time permits I will give this a shot.